# Creating Rails associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, relationships, model-associations

I'm having a hard time understanding how to create the following associations:

- User has many photo albums
- Photo Album has many photos
- Users can follow someone else's specific photo album (and indirectly they end up following the photo album's owner) and have the photos show up in a "news feed" type scenario, so there has to be some sort of relationship set up between them

Here's the associations I have:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :photo_albums
  has_many :photos
  has_many :relationships, :foreign_key => "follower_id", 
                           :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :reverse_relationships, :foreign_key => "followed_id", 
                                   :class_name => "Relationship", 
                                   :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :followings, :through => :relationships, :source => :followed
  has_many :followers, :through => :reverse_relationships, :source => :follower
end

class PhotoAlbum < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :photos
end

class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :photo_album
end

class Relationship < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :follower, :foreign_key => "follower_id", :class_name => "User"
  belongs_to :followed, :foreign_key => "followed_id", :class_name => "User"
end
```

How can I make it to where I can just get all the photos from the photo albums the user is following?

**Example:**

- Jane has 2 photo albums, "Jane's Public Stuff" and "Jane's Private
  Stuff" with photos in each of them.
- Bob follows ONLY "Jane's Public Stuff" so how can I return the photos
  from only that photo album via ActiveRecord associations?

Something like `bob.followings.photos` that returns photos from ONLY the photo albums that Bob is following... or even `bob.followings.photo_albums` to get a collection of all the photo albums that Bob is following

I know there's probably a long way to do this, but is there an easier way using ActiveRecord associations?

Thanks for any advice or guidance you can provide!  I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you have it set up, following associates a User to another User, not a User to a PhotoAlbum, which is what you describe. It sounds as though you want

```
class Relationship < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :follower, :foreign_key => "follower_id", :class_name => "User"
  belongs_to :followed, :foreign_key => "photo_album_id", :class_name => "PhotoAlbum"
end
```

With that done, a slight modification of davidb's answer should give you what you want:

```
def followings_photos
      Photo.where(:photo_album_id => self.followings.collect(&:id))
end
```

Comment: Ahhh, I was so close!  Thank you!!!!  Now I can do stuff like `bob.followings.group_by(&:user_id).count` to get how many people he's following too.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look at the `amistad` gem at https://github.com/raw1z/amistad, which gives you friends and friendships functionality. In your case, a friend would be a follower.

Then you can do something like `user.friends.each do |f|` to retrieve all the followers of `user` and then `f.photos` to get all the photos from each follower.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I'd like to see if I can accomplish this using AR associations prior going the long route of a do loop or complex SQL

Answer (score 1):

try this in User model:

```
def followings_photos
      Photo.where(:user_id => self.followings.collect(&:id))
end
```

Comment: Thanks David, but that collects all photos from all people they are following, even if they are not following the photo album that the photo is in.  I'd like it to where it only returns photos from the photo albums they are following

Comment: I added an example to the original question to better explain it